# Can't convert a view to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a view to bitmap. I'm following this snippet of code which takes a view and returns a bitmap

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
   view=getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`

Here's the view in xml, I tried changing the width and height to dp, but no changes

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bg_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/green_bg">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_circle">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/percentTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="80%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What's actually wrong in here?

Comment: where are you calling screenShot()? inside Activity onCreate?

Comment: view.getDrawingCache()==null.

Comment: yes, inside oncreate